# exponential of a matrix in Fortran using Taylor Series expansion

Tags: fortran

I am having a matrix of `n x n` and I want to calculate exponential_of_matrix(matrix_name) in Fortran. Is there anyone who knows to calculate the exponential of a matrix using Taylor Series Expansion?

```
Taylor Series Expansion of e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + x^4/4! + .....
```

I tried to write a matrix multiplication subroutine which may be useful during writing matrix exponential subroutine.

```
! mat_mul: matrix_a(n,m) matrix_b(m,l) product(n,l)

subroutine mat_mul(matrix_a,matrix_b, product,n,m,l)
    real*8 matrix_a(n,m), matrix_b(m,l), product(n,l)
    integer i,j,k
    do i=1,n
        do j=1,l
            product(i,j) = 0
            do k=1,m
                product(i,j) = product(i,j) + matrix_a(i,k) * matrix_b(k,j)
            end do
        end do
    end do
end subroutine mat_mul
```

Comment: You definitely should not write your own matrix multiplication. Not the naive anyway. You can use MATMUL for small cases. When it becomes too small, there is GEMM in BLAS.

Comment: There is loads of numerical mathematics and computtional science literature about the matrix exponential. A very quick web search showed this among the top hits [How and How Not to Compute theExponential of a Matrix](https://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/talks/exp09.pdf). There are libraries available ready to use, e.g. https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/matrix_exponential/matrix_exponential.html (requires another library).

Comment: Thank you @VladimirF . I am aware of MATMUL() I was writing code from scratch.

Comment: `Matmul` is part of the Fortran language. How is using it not writing code from scratch?

Comment: A classic reference on the subject https://www.jstor.org/stable/2029743

Comment: No, actually I wrote this subroutine when I was unaware of MATMUL.

Comment: @IanBush Very nice. There is also a sequel or update https://www.jstor.org/stable/25054364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written this subroutine using Taylor Series Expansion. Instead of `mat_mul` subroutine, its better to use `MATMUL(matrix_A,matrix_B)`.

```
subroutine exponent_matrix(a,expo_mat,n)
    real a(n,n), prod(n,n), expo_mat(n,n), term(n,n)
    do i=1,n
        do j=1,n
            if(i .eq. j) then
                expo_mat(i,j) =1
                term(i,j) = 1
            else
                expo_mat(i,j) = 0
                term(i,j) = 0
            end if
        end do
    end do
    
    do i=1,5000
        call mat_mul(term,a,prod,n,n,n)
        term = prod/i
        expo_mat = expo_mat + term
    end do
end subroutine exponent_matrix
```

Comment: Note real*8 is not and has never been part of the standard Fortran language, and as an extension may not be available on all platforms. Please learn about kind values - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to multiply matrices you should really use [matmul](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MATMUL.html)<sup>1</sup> rather than doing it manually, so

```
do i=1,n
  do j=1,l
    product(i,j) = 0
    do k=1,m
      product(i,j) = product(i,j) + matrix_a(i,k) * matrix_b(k,j)
    end do
  end do
end do
```

becomes

```
product = matmul(matrix_a, matrix_b)
```

This code is clearer, and significantly faster.

Second, are you sure you want to use Taylor series? If the matrix is diagonalisable then matrix exponentiation is typically calculated via [diagonalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Computing_the_matrix_exponential):

1. Diagonalise the matrix to get its eigenvectors `v_i` and eigenvalues `e_i`.
2. Taking the exponential of the eigenvalues `e^e_i`.
3. Construct the matrix with eigenvectors `v_i` and eigenvalues `e^e_i`.

---

<sup>1</sup> or even a [BLAS/LAPACK](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node11.html) distribution if you need more performance.