# Raise a matrix to a power

Tags: fortran, lapack, blas

Suppose we have a Hermitian matrix `A` that is known to have an inverse.

I know that `ZGETRF` and `ZGETRI` subroutines in LAPACK library can compute the inverse matrix.

Is there any subroutine in LAPACK or BLAS library can calculate `A^{-1/2}` directly or any other way to compute `A^{-1/2}`?

Comment: No, there are no LAPACK routines to do this directly, though you can probably use a few routines together to get what you want, assuming it exists. Does A have any other nice properties, e.g. Hermitian? And *why* do you want this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [exponential of a matrix in Fortran using Taylor Series expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70728907/exponential-of-a-matrix-in-fortran-using-taylor-series-expansion). Oh, no sorry, thats `e^matrix`, not `matrix^n`. I guess do the same thing, but with `(e_i)^{-1/}` rather than `e^{e_i}`.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for the reply. The complex matrix A is Hermitian. I need to compute A^{-1/2} as the intermediate data for the following calculation.

Comment: @veryreverie Thank you for the reply. I only want compute the exponential value of the complex matrix and the exponential is -1/2. That post explains how to compute the Taylor expansion with a matrix as the exponential term. It is different from what I want to calculate.

Comment: @Kieran I've taken the liberty of changing your title, as I believe the "exponential of a matrix" refers to `e^A`, not `A^n`. See e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential). Feel free to rollback if you disagree.

Comment: OK, diagonalising it with ZHEEV and find it that way is as easy as any - I don't claim it is optimal but it will get the job done. But *what* is the next step? If e.g. this is part of solving a generalised eigenvalue problem and A is also positive definite there are better ways to solve it than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise a matrix to a power following a similar procedure to [taking the exponential of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70729215/8559300):

1. Diagonalise the matrix, to give the eigenvectors `v_i` and corresponding eigenvalues `e_i`.
2. Raise the eigenvalues to the power, `{e_i}^{-1/2}`.
3. Construct the matrix whose eigenalues are `{e_i}^{-1/2}` and whose eigenvectors are `v_i`.

It's worth noting that, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix), this problem does not have a unique solution. In step 2 above, both `{e_i}^{-1/2}` and `-{e_i}^{-1/2}` will lead to valid solutions, so an `N*N` matrix `A` will have at least `2^N` matrices `B` such that `B^{-2}=A`. If any of the eigenvalues are degenerate then there will be a continuous space of valid solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested solution. Can I ask one more question? If A is a 2000 by 2000 complex matrix. I think that diagonalising it may encounters the 'out-of-RAM' issue. Do you have any other idea to compute A^{-1/2}? Thank you again.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix has some ideas. I can't give any more concrete suggestions without knowing more about your problem. I suggest asking a new Stack Overflow question with more details.